# how to move files outside of root

Tags: codeigniter

I've looked around, but haven't found a helpful article on this. I don't know how to move files above the root so they're not directly accessible. My ftp client, doesn't give any option to go above, and I'm clueless.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "root" the answer might very well be "there *is* nowhere above the root."  We're going to need more details about your server.  What OS?  What kind of server (web, ftp, mail, etc)?  You want the files to be inccessible in what context?

Comment: It really depends on the access that you have on whatever server you're logging into.  Is this a linux server?

You are probably 'chrooted' to a certain directory, say /var/www/somedomain.com for instance.

If so, you aren't allowed to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a server through fatcow.com so the directory looks like /hermes/web06/b2521/moo.account_user_name/ - Basically I don't know if it's possible to move these files outside of the public_html.

Comment: It sounds like you have what's known as a shared hosting account, and you are chroot jailed to your user/home path.  Ask them if you are "jailed."  And regardless, ask for SSH access, FTP sucks

Comment: Yep, I'm jailed, got any host recommendations that are affordable yet don't restrict you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do in putty `mv filename ..` or you can do `cd ..` to go up one directory.

Comment: `mv ..` will do nothing: `mv: missing destination file operand after \`..'`

Comment: I'm using a Mac OS, would I have to connect to my server with terminal, and move the files that way?

Comment: So I created an FTP connection with terminal to my server. I can't cd up a directory, and mv keeps giving me invalid command

Answer (score -1):

I called up my service provider, and with Fatcow, it's just not possible to go above the root folder.